# Windows XP is loading slower for one user

Tags: windows-xp

I have 2 users in Win XP:

1. common user, under which I work most of the time.
2. admin, that I created for the sake of security.

But when I log off the normal user and login as admin, the machine seems to start and work faster.

Where should I check to find the differences between the processes, starting under these users?

Comment: Is this on a domain?  Are there apps that load as the regular user and not admin?

Answer (score 0):

Run CCleaner on the slower user and clear any profile specific files.

Check startup for that user.  Keep minimum stuff in startup.

Answer (score 0):

As well, try running a `CHKDSK C: /f /r` I've seen corrupted files, especially the registry hives, cause slow downs and even complete account lock outs before

Answer (score 0):

1. Login as the user in question.
2. Click the Start Menu, click `Run`, and type `msconfig`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to the `Startup` tab. This tab will display everything that runs on startup from the registry or from the `Startup` folder in the Start Menua-> All Programs list.
4. Look for any Start Up items or Manufacturers that look strange. Check for any commands that look like they might be unusual (versus the other examples you see). Uncheck any item you want to disable starting up.

**WARNING:** Make *sure* you know what you are unchecking before you press apply or ok. You can negatively affect your computer by stopping certain startup items. On the positive note you can undo anything that had a negative affect by re doing all the above steps.

Once you are done going through the list, press <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>. Choose to either <kbd>Restart now</kbd> or <kbd>Restart Later</kbd>. You will have to log off this user before it takes affect.